# My Intel AX200 wifi adapter can't connect to internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-adapter

I've got an odd case of no internet.

I have a AX200 integrated to my Gigabyte Aorus Pro AX (Z590) mobo. Upstairs in my office, sometimes it says discovered 2 internet connections (my home and guest networks), but always only shows that one dot, meaning the connection is extremely unstable. Other devices in the same room can connect easily, and even a 5 yr old USB adapter shows all 4 wifi thingies (albeit >2000ms ping...). However, downstairs near the router the integrated adapter can connect easily, and runs really fast. Have I received a defective copy or is this a software issue? If it is, Im pretty sure Ive tried everything without downloading external resetting software.

Comment: Have you checked that the antennae are in good condition, i.e., the middle pins of the connectors aren't bent and the wires aren't abraded or creased? Putting them in a different location might help.

Comment: no, I was thinking of doing that... Ill try that today

Comment: @AndrewMorton
You know how there is a sheild thingy blocking the inside of the motherboard io connectors? It turns out the adapter is somewhere under there and since it has rgb lighting... I heard on reddit that you have to unscrew and untangle all those rgb cables & stuff just to access the wifi card so I probably wont do that... maybe there is a simpler way?

Comment: I wasn't referring to the cables going to the card: I meant the external antennae - I wouldn't mess with the fiddly tiny connectors on the WiFi card. Or do the antennae screw directly onto the I/O panel? If so, perhaps you'd be better off with an external WiFi antenna - one with two SMA connectors, not a USB connector.

Comment: Because the adapter works properly when it's close to the router and not when it's far away, it looks more like a signal strength problem than a software problem. Because other equipment in the upstairs room works, it doesn't appear to be an electrical interference problem.

Comment: Oh, and those connectors should only be done up finger-tight to avoid damage.

Comment: @AndrewMorton
so this means I will have to buy 2 sma antennae? There are 2 sma connectors on the io panel of the motherboard... one for 2.4ghz and 5ghz i assume?  sorry late reply

Comment: They would have come in the box with the motherboard, if you still have that and were wondering what some of the parts were.

Comment: omg omg omg i think you are right..... lemme check

Comment: YES YOU WERE TYSM LIFE SAVER!!!

Comment: wait one more thing: there are 2 connectors - does it matter which one I screw into which wifi port thingy?

Comment: You can connect them either way round. You should find the Bluetooth starts working a lot better too, if you use that.

Comment: ok thanks! so helpfull!

Comment: You're welcome :) I made the useful comments into an answer for you. After some time, you should be able to click the grey checkmark if you want to accept it: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Because the adapter works properly when it's close to the router and not when it's far away, it looks more like a signal strength problem than a software problem. Because other equipment in the upstairs room works, it doesn't appear to be an electrical interference problem.

The next thing to look at is the state of the antennae - the connectors should be done up finger-tight only; check that the centre conductor is not bent; and if they are on wires, check the wires for kinks or abrasions.

If there aren't any antennae connected, look in the box the motherboard came in. The SMA connectors can be connected either way round.